# PHP: Combinar jQuery AJaX con MVC

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mvc, poo

Estoy adaptando una web con código estructurado a POO + MVC y al intentar incluir uno de mis scripts jQuery con `ajax()` me está dando un problema que antes no ocurría, y es que la respuesta (que debería ser únicamente un dígito entre 0 y 3) incluye el HTML de la cabecera (y del pie), por lo que el script no sabe interpretarlo:

[image: Cabecera]

El HTML del pie puedo ocultarlo con un `if`, pero, claro, la cabecera no porque entonces deja de funcionar JS...

Por resumir un poco el código, se trata del registro de usuarios; los datos del formulario (la vista) se envían por el método `POST` al método `registrar()` del controlador `Usuarios`, que devuelve un número de 0 a 3 en función de qué haya ocurrido:

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST', url: '', data: {nombre: nombre, correo: correo, contrasena: contrasena, contrasena2: contrasena2},
        success: function(respuesta)
        {
            if(respuesta == 1) swal("¡Bienvenido!", "¡Ya eres uno más de la familia!", "success", {button: false}).then(function(){formulario.trigger('reset');});
            else if(respuesta == 2) swal("Vaya...", "Nombre repetido; tendrás que elegir uno diferente... ;)", "info", {button: false}).then(function(){nombre.trigger('reset');});
            else if(respuesta == 3) swal("Vaya...", "Correo repetido; tendrás que elegir uno diferente... ;)", "info", {button: false}).then(function(){nombre.trigger('reset');});
            else swal("Ups...", "Algo ha fallado; intenta registrarte de nuevo más tarde...", "error", {button: false});
        },
        error: function()
        {
            swal("Ups...", "Algo ha fallado; intenta registrarte de nuevo más tarde...", "error", {button: false});
        }
    });
```

Al principio tenía dudas sobre cómo proporcionarle la URL a AJaX, pero dejándola vacía, al estar el formulario incluido en el método, parece que funciona:

```
class UsuariosC // Controlador de usuarios
    {
        function registrar() // Método para procesar el registro de usuarios
        {
            if($_POST) // Si detecta un envío POST procede a registrar al usuario
            {   
                foreach($_POST as $clave => $valor) $$clave = $valor;

                $usuario = new UsuariosM; // Se crea un objeto de tipo usuario

                $usuario->establecer("nombre", $nombre); // Se le asignan sus atributos a partir de las variables POST
                $usuario->establecer("correo", $correo);
                $usuario->establecer("contrasena", $contrasena);

                $resultados = $usuario->comprobar(); // Se comprueba si el nombre y el correo ya están en uso

                while($fila = $resultados->fetch_object())
                {
                    if($usuario->obtener("nombre") == $fila->nombre_usuario) 
                    {
                        $respuesta = 2;
                        break;
                    } 
                    elseif($usuario->obtener("correo") == $fila->correo) $respuesta = 3;
                }

                if($respuesta) echo $respuesta;
                else 
                {
                    $respuesta = $usuario->registrar(); // Si no están en uso, se procede a su registro

                    echo $respuesta;
                }
            }
            else require_once("vistas/usuarios/registro.php"); // Si no hay envío POST, visualiza el formulario de registro 
        }
    }
```

Y como podéis comprobar en la captura de pantalla, el proceso funciona -en este caso devuelve un 2, porque probé a registrarme con un nombre que ya está en la base de datos-, pero al mezclarse con el HTML de la cabecera -que se incluye con un `require_once` en el `index.php`- el script se va por el `else` porque no le llega el entero que está esperando.

¿Sabéis a qué puede deberse?

**EDICIÓN:**

Una posibilidad es incluir algo como esto en el `if` del *script*:

```
else if(respuesta.includes("<body>2"))
```

Pero es una chapuza.... Y además en el siguiente *script* que haga uso de `ajax()` voy a estar en las mismas.

**EDICIÓN 2:**

Lo he solucionado creando un archivo `ajax.php` en el directorio raíz desde el que se llama al controlador:

```
<?php

    require_once("autocargador.php");

    $usuario = new UsuariosC;

    $respuesta = $usuario->registro();

    echo $respuesta;

?>
```

He intentado meterlo en algún subdirectorio pero no soy capaz de definir la ruta para que encuentre el controlador y a su vez éste al modelo... Supongo que tenga que modificar el archivo con una cadena de `if` a medida que vaya implementando diferentes *scripts* con `ajax()`.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de devolver tu respuesta, puedes setear el tipo de respuesta usando:

`header('Content-type: text/plain');`

Comment: Devuelve toda la cabecera pero como texto plano -sale negro en vez de en color-.